# python ast SyntaxError: invalid syntax for unknown reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, dictionary, abstract-syntax-tree

I have this string which I do not control or wrote but need to parse it using `ast`. `ast` can not deal with it. But I need to know why? and how to overcome this issue?

Here is my code:

```
import ast

mystring = "https://111.com<xx>{'Server': 'openresty', 'Date': 'Fri, 19 Apr 2019 07:31:18 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding, Accept-Encoding', 'X-Rid': '5cbcdcf186159173e59ed3463f0b6ff3', 'P3p': 'CP="Tumblr's privacy policy is available here: https://www.tumblr.com/policy/en/privacy"', 'X-Xss-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Tumblr-User': 'the-absolute-best-posts', 'X-Tumblr-Pixel-0': 'https://px.srvcs.tumblr.com/impixu?T=1555659077&J=eyJ0eXBlIjoidXJsIiwidXJsIjoiaHR0cDovLzEwMDBub3Rlcy5jb20vIiwicmVxdHlwZSI6MCwicm91dGUiOiIvIn0=&U=EJEPFDDMDN&K=36533553ca6c98c3ffa40d15855478b3c1f427a30be7a5eb4cd09256b4cd31a7--https://px.srvcs.tumblr.com/impixu?T=1555659077&J=eyJ0eXBlIjoicG9zdCIsInVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly8xMDAwbm90ZXMuY29tLyIsInJlcXR5cGUiOjAsInJvdXRlIjoiLyIsInBvc3RzIjpbeyJyb290X2Jsb2dpZCI6IjE4NjcxODA4Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOiIxMjMzNTczMjcxMSIsInBvc3RpZCI6IjE4NDI5MDIxOTE4OCIsImJsb2dp', 'X-Tumblr-Pixel-1': 'ZCI6IjE5MzQzMzciLCJzb3VyY2UiOjMzfSx7InJvb3RfYmxvZ2lkIjoiMjE0ODQzNTciLCJyb290X3Bvc3RpZCI6OTIyNTc2MTQxMTUsInBvc3RpZCI6IjE4NDI5MDAxNDkyOCIsImJsb2dpZCI6IjE5MzQzMzciLCJzb3VyY2UiOjMzfSx7InJvb3RfYmxvZ2lkIjoiNzMyMzk2NSIsInJvb3RfcG9zdGlkIjoiMTEwMjk5NjAyNDU2IiwicG9zdGlkIjoiMTg0Mjg5Nzk5OTY4IiwiYmxvZ2lkIjoiMTkzNDMzNyIsInNvdXJjZSI6MzN9LHsicm9vdF9ibG9naWQiOiI5NDg5NzU4Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOjQ1MzczNTgwMDc0LCJwb3N0aWQiOiIxODQyODk1NjkzNDgiLCJibG9naWQiOiIxOTM0MzM3Iiwic291cmNlIjozM30seyJyb290X2Jsb2dpZCI6Ij', 'X-Tumblr-Pixel-2': 'ExMTY2NTU5Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOiIxMjgyMDQ1MzczMTUiLCJwb3N0aWQiOiIxODQyODkzMjcyNTMiLCJibG9naWQiOiIxOTM0MzM3Iiwic291cmNlIjozM30seyJyb290X2Jsb2dpZCI6IjU2NjI0Mzg2Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOjQyMzY1MDI4NDM1LCJwb3N0aWQiOiIxODQyODkwNjgzNjMiLCJibG9naWQiOiIxOTM0MzM3Iiwic291cmNlIjozM30seyJyb290X2Jsb2dpZCI6IjcyMjc2MzI5Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOiIxMzc0ODA5NjA2NjciLCJwb3N0aWQiOiIxODQyODg4MDczNDMiLCJibG9naWQiOiIxOTM0MzM3Iiwic291cmNlIjozM31dfQ==&U=LFCMCFJHJM&K=600602e5cc72d6cd698d22736e67fbcabad4b929587949814298', 'X-Tumblr-Pixel-3': '57d2040fa3bb', 'X-Tumblr-Pixel': '4', 'Link': '\<https://66.media.tumblr.com/avatar_6d0dd0685eab_128.pnj>; rel=icon', 'X-UA-Compatible': 'IE=Edge,chrome=1', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}"

h = mystring.split("<xx>",1)[1]
h = ast.literal_eval(h.strip())
```

What I get is invalid syntax error:

```
>   File "test.py", line 3
>     mystring = "https://111.com<xx>{'Server': 'openresty', 'Date': 'Fri, 19 Apr 2019 07:31:18 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html;
> charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection':
> 'keep-alive', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding, Accept-Encoding', 'X-Rid':
> '5cbcdcf186159173e59ed3463f0b6ff3', 'P3p': 'CP="Tumblr's privacy
> policy is available here: https://www.tumblr.com/policy/en/privacy"',
> 'X-Xss-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'X-Content-Type-Options':
> 'nosniff', 'X-Tumblr-User': 'the-absolute-best-posts',
> 'X-Tumblr-Pixel-0':
> 'https://px.srvcs.tumblr.com/impixu?T=1555659077&J=eyJ0eXBlIjoidXJsIiwidXJsIjoiaHR0cDovLzEwMDBub3Rlcy5jb20vIiwicmVxdHlwZSI6MCwicm91dGUiOiIvIn0=&U=EJEPFDDMDN&K=36533553ca6c98c3ffa40d15855478b3c1f427a30be7a5eb4cd09256b4cd31a7--https://px.srvcs.tumblr.com/impixu?T=1555659077&J=eyJ0eXBlIjoicG9zdCIsInVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly8xMDAwbm90ZXMuY29tLyIsInJlcXR5cGUiOjAsInJvdXRlIjoiLyIsInBvc3RzIjpbeyJyb290X2Jsb2dpZCI6IjE4NjcxODA4Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOiIxMjMzNTczMjcxMSIsInBvc3RpZCI6IjE4NDI5MDIxOTE4OCIsImJsb2dp',
> 'X-Tumblr-Pixel-1':
> 'ZCI6IjE5MzQzMzciLCJzb3VyY2UiOjMzfSx7InJvb3RfYmxvZ2lkIjoiMjE0ODQzNTciLCJyb290X3Bvc3RpZCI6OTIyNTc2MTQxMTUsInBvc3RpZCI6IjE4NDI5MDAxNDkyOCIsImJsb2dpZCI6IjE5MzQzMzciLCJzb3VyY2UiOjMzfSx7InJvb3RfYmxvZ2lkIjoiNzMyMzk2NSIsInJvb3RfcG9zdGlkIjoiMTEwMjk5NjAyNDU2IiwicG9zdGlkIjoiMTg0Mjg5Nzk5OTY4IiwiYmxvZ2lkIjoiMTkzNDMzNyIsInNvdXJjZSI6MzN9LHsicm9vdF9ibG9naWQiOiI5NDg5NzU4Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOjQ1MzczNTgwMDc0LCJwb3N0aWQiOiIxODQyODk1NjkzNDgiLCJibG9naWQiOiIxOTM0MzM3Iiwic291cmNlIjozM30seyJyb290X2Jsb2dpZCI6Ij',
> 'X-Tumblr-Pixel-2':
> 'ExMTY2NTU5Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOiIxMjgyMDQ1MzczMTUiLCJwb3N0aWQiOiIxODQyODkzMjcyNTMiLCJibG9naWQiOiIxOTM0MzM3Iiwic291cmNlIjozM30seyJyb290X2Jsb2dpZCI6IjU2NjI0Mzg2Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOjQyMzY1MDI4NDM1LCJwb3N0aWQiOiIxODQyODkwNjgzNjMiLCJibG9naWQiOiIxOTM0MzM3Iiwic291cmNlIjozM30seyJyb290X2Jsb2dpZCI6IjcyMjc2MzI5Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOiIxMzc0ODA5NjA2NjciLCJwb3N0aWQiOiIxODQyODg4MDczNDMiLCJibG9naWQiOiIxOTM0MzM3Iiwic291cmNlIjozM31dfQ==&U=LFCMCFJHJM&K=600602e5cc72d6cd698d22736e67fbcabad4b929587949814298',
> 'X-Tumblr-Pixel-3': '57d2040fa3bb', 'X-Tumblr-Pixel': '4', 'Link':
> '\<https://66.media.tumblr.com/avatar_6d0dd0685eab_128.pnj>;
> rel=icon', 'X-UA-Compatible': 'IE=Edge,chrome=1', 'Content-Encoding':
> 'gzip'}"
> 
> 
> 
>     ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: There's a double quote halfway through the string.

Comment: `...P3p': 'CP="Tumblr's privacy policy is available here: http...` in this part

Comment: You may need a 'divide and conquer' approach here. Either shorten the string by removing obviously correct parts, or try to split it into smaller and smaller parts and test each part.

Comment: Even though, I tried to surround the string with triple quotes `"""` and also tried to manually remove the half-way double quotes but still the problem there. I can not remove double quotes manually. I have many records with parsing error. How to overcome the issue automatically?

Comment: Perhaps you could change all double quotes: `"` within the string with 'triple-quotes': `"""` so that line breaks are considered part of a string.

Comment: I did but this does not solve the problem. Also this is just for the sake of example. But in fact the string is not hard coded in the code. It is being read from a file. So I can not add triple quotes in my real situation.

Comment: Its not the double quotes `"` its the apostrophe as in `Tumblr's privacy`. I tried your code and the `^` pointed me directly to the problem. I removed the apostrophe and your code produced a dict that I could print.

Comment: I have many cases like this. Is there anyway for the library to deal with this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193193/discussion-between-quamrana-and-none).

Comment: This looks like an *XY Problem*. The string presented here doesn't look OK (it's probably printed and suffered some formatting). Things shouldn't be that hard. As a note: **Triple quote it, and you won't get the error from the question**.How do you get the strings? You should place the exact scenario.

Comment: I've just run into SyntaxError: unknown parsing error, and it turned out to be a file encoding issue. Once I've converted .py file to ASCII, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a syntax error because the string/json includes double quotes, which end the declaration of the string prematurely. With as a result that Python tries to interpret the rest at valid python code, which it of course is not.

This part seems to be the problem:

```
3p': 'CP="Tumblr's privacy policy is available...
```

Comment: Have you tried? It is not the problem. I tried. It does not solve it

Comment: I have tried and it does fix the syntax error, but the last two lines now cause a new error. I'll have a look

Comment: I do not need manual solutions. If it can be automated by the library or that I use another library, manual solutions do not help me as I have a lot of such cases. I can manually remove quotes.

Answer (score 0):

try with this syntax instead

```
import ast

mystring = "https://111.com<xx>{'Server': 'openresty', 'Date': 'Fri, 19 Apr 2019 07:31:18 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding, Accept-Encoding', 'X-Rid': '5cbcdcf186159173e59ed3463f0b6ff3', 'P3p': 'CP='Tumblr\'s privacy policy is available here: https://www.tumblr.com/policy/en/privacy', 'X-Xss-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Tumblr-User': 'the-absolute-best-posts', 'X-Tumblr-Pixel-0': 'https://px.srvcs.tumblr.com/impixu?T=1555659077&J=eyJ0eXBlIjoidXJsIiwidXJsIjoiaHR0cDovLzEwMDBub3Rlcy5jb20vIiwicmVxdHlwZSI6MCwicm91dGUiOiIvIn0=&U=EJEPFDDMDN&K=36533553ca6c98c3ffa40d15855478b3c1f427a30be7a5eb4cd09256b4cd31a7--https://px.srvcs.tumblr.com/impixu?T=1555659077&J=eyJ0eXBlIjoicG9zdCIsInVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly8xMDAwbm90ZXMuY29tLyIsInJlcXR5cGUiOjAsInJvdXRlIjoiLyIsInBvc3RzIjpbeyJyb290X2Jsb2dpZCI6IjE4NjcxODA4Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOiIxMjMzNTczMjcxMSIsInBvc3RpZCI6IjE4NDI5MDIxOTE4OCIsImJsb2dp', 'X-Tumblr-Pixel-1': 'ZCI6IjE5MzQzMzciLCJzb3VyY2UiOjMzfSx7InJvb3RfYmxvZ2lkIjoiMjE0ODQzNTciLCJyb290X3Bvc3RpZCI6OTIyNTc2MTQxMTUsInBvc3RpZCI6IjE4NDI5MDAxNDkyOCIsImJsb2dpZCI6IjE5MzQzMzciLCJzb3VyY2UiOjMzfSx7InJvb3RfYmxvZ2lkIjoiNzMyMzk2NSIsInJvb3RfcG9zdGlkIjoiMTEwMjk5NjAyNDU2IiwicG9zdGlkIjoiMTg0Mjg5Nzk5OTY4IiwiYmxvZ2lkIjoiMTkzNDMzNyIsInNvdXJjZSI6MzN9LHsicm9vdF9ibG9naWQiOiI5NDg5NzU4Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOjQ1MzczNTgwMDc0LCJwb3N0aWQiOiIxODQyODk1NjkzNDgiLCJibG9naWQiOiIxOTM0MzM3Iiwic291cmNlIjozM30seyJyb290X2Jsb2dpZCI6Ij', 'X-Tumblr-Pixel-2': 'ExMTY2NTU5Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOiIxMjgyMDQ1MzczMTUiLCJwb3N0aWQiOiIxODQyODkzMjcyNTMiLCJibG9naWQiOiIxOTM0MzM3Iiwic291cmNlIjozM30seyJyb290X2Jsb2dpZCI6IjU2NjI0Mzg2Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOjQyMzY1MDI4NDM1LCJwb3N0aWQiOiIxODQyODkwNjgzNjMiLCJibG9naWQiOiIxOTM0MzM3Iiwic291cmNlIjozM30seyJyb290X2Jsb2dpZCI6IjcyMjc2MzI5Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOiIxMzc0ODA5NjA2NjciLCJwb3N0aWQiOiIxODQyODg4MDczNDMiLCJibG9naWQiOiIxOTM0MzM3Iiwic291cmNlIjozM31dfQ==&U=LFCMCFJHJM&K=600602e5cc72d6cd698d22736e67fbcabad4b929587949814298', 'X-Tumblr-Pixel-3': '57d2040fa3bb', 'X-Tumblr-Pixel': '4', 'Link': '\<https://66.media.tumblr.com/avatar_6d0dd0685eab_128.pnj>; rel=icon', 'X-UA-Compatible': 'IE=Edge,chrome=1', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}"

h = mystring.split("<xx>",1)[1]
h = ast.literal_eval(h.strip())
```

you had a problem with the double quotes at `'P3p': 'CP="Tumblr's ....`

Comment: What did you change? So I knwo what is the source of the problem?

Comment: I tried to remove the double quotes. Still not working.

Comment: your problem is beceause literal_eval only evaluates a single literal

Comment: Is there any alternative library that can deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import ast

mystring = "https://111.com<xx>{'Server': 'openresty', 'Date': 'Fri, 19 Apr 2019 07:31:18 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding, Accept-Encoding', 'X-Rid': '5cbcdcf186159173e59ed3463f0b6ff3', 'P3p': 'CP=\"Tumblr\\'s privacy policy is available here: https://www.tumblr.com/policy/en/privacy\"', 'X-Xss-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Tumblr-User': 'the-absolute-best-posts', 'X-Tumblr-Pixel-0': 'https://px.srvcs.tumblr.com/impixu?T=1555659077&J=eyJ0eXBlIjoidXJsIiwidXJsIjoiaHR0cDovLzEwMDBub3Rlcy5jb20vIiwicmVxdHlwZSI6MCwicm91dGUiOiIvIn0=&U=EJEPFDDMDN&K=36533553ca6c98c3ffa40d15855478b3c1f427a30be7a5eb4cd09256b4cd31a7--https://px.srvcs.tumblr.com/impixu?T=1555659077&J=eyJ0eXBlIjoicG9zdCIsInVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly8xMDAwbm90ZXMuY29tLyIsInJlcXR5cGUiOjAsInJvdXRlIjoiLyIsInBvc3RzIjpbeyJyb290X2Jsb2dpZCI6IjE4NjcxODA4Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOiIxMjMzNTczMjcxMSIsInBvc3RpZCI6IjE4NDI5MDIxOTE4OCIsImJsb2dp', 'X-Tumblr-Pixel-1': 'ZCI6IjE5MzQzMzciLCJzb3VyY2UiOjMzfSx7InJvb3RfYmxvZ2lkIjoiMjE0ODQzNTciLCJyb290X3Bvc3RpZCI6OTIyNTc2MTQxMTUsInBvc3RpZCI6IjE4NDI5MDAxNDkyOCIsImJsb2dpZCI6IjE5MzQzMzciLCJzb3VyY2UiOjMzfSx7InJvb3RfYmxvZ2lkIjoiNzMyMzk2NSIsInJvb3RfcG9zdGlkIjoiMTEwMjk5NjAyNDU2IiwicG9zdGlkIjoiMTg0Mjg5Nzk5OTY4IiwiYmxvZ2lkIjoiMTkzNDMzNyIsInNvdXJjZSI6MzN9LHsicm9vdF9ibG9naWQiOiI5NDg5NzU4Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOjQ1MzczNTgwMDc0LCJwb3N0aWQiOiIxODQyODk1NjkzNDgiLCJibG9naWQiOiIxOTM0MzM3Iiwic291cmNlIjozM30seyJyb290X2Jsb2dpZCI6Ij', 'X-Tumblr-Pixel-2': 'ExMTY2NTU5Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOiIxMjgyMDQ1MzczMTUiLCJwb3N0aWQiOiIxODQyODkzMjcyNTMiLCJibG9naWQiOiIxOTM0MzM3Iiwic291cmNlIjozM30seyJyb290X2Jsb2dpZCI6IjU2NjI0Mzg2Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOjQyMzY1MDI4NDM1LCJwb3N0aWQiOiIxODQyODkwNjgzNjMiLCJibG9naWQiOiIxOTM0MzM3Iiwic291cmNlIjozM30seyJyb290X2Jsb2dpZCI6IjcyMjc2MzI5Iiwicm9vdF9wb3N0aWQiOiIxMzc0ODA5NjA2NjciLCJwb3N0aWQiOiIxODQyODg4MDczNDMiLCJibG9naWQiOiIxOTM0MzM3Iiwic291cmNlIjozM31dfQ==&U=LFCMCFJHJM&K=600602e5cc72d6cd698d22736e67fbcabad4b929587949814298', 'X-Tumblr-Pixel-3': '57d2040fa3bb', 'X-Tumblr-Pixel': '4', 'Link': '\<https://66.media.tumblr.com/avatar_6d0dd0685eab_128.pnj>; rel=icon', 'X-UA-Compatible': 'IE=Edge,chrome=1', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}"

h = mystring.split("<xx>",1)[1]
h = ast.literal_eval(h.strip())
```

You have `"` in your quote (and a `'` in that quote) which is messing up the parsing. You need to escape them

```
'P3p': 'CP=\"Tumblr\\'s privacy policy is available here: https://www.tumblr.com/policy/en/privacy\"',
```

Why do you want to put this string and parse it with `ast` anyway? There must be a better way of getting what you want. Maybe store a JSON file and `json.load()` or `json.loads()` it?

Comment: I have big data. So how to automate this as there are 100s of such cases. Can't do this manually.

Comment: The correct way is to save the JSON as a JSON file, and use the `json` library to load it, like I said. This should happen before whatever step you ran that turned your data into a string that contains a URL and a JSON object.

Comment: If you provide a complete answer with how to solve it in json without manually changing the data, this will be an acceptable solution.

Comment: @None How did you make that string you're passing to `ast`? I can't really help you without more context. The place to fix this is before you get into this situation of having a string in a python file you're trying to parse with `ast`.